# Moderator support request

Tags: support, moderation

I would like to speak with a moderator in regards to an issue which I would not like to have known to the general public. I personally believe that the issue may be somewhat time-sensitive. I don't know how to contact or request contact from a moderator. Is there anything that I can do to initiate a private conversation with any moderator?

Answer (score 4):

**If you need to contact the community team:** There's a [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

**If you simply need to tell a moderator about something, but you don't need the community team:** Flag a post as *other* and put your message in there.

Please note that neither of these should be used for messages like *Hey, I like your answer* or *Why is my flag declined?*. In those cases, ask a mod in chat, or comment on the post.

Comment: How do I find a mod in chat? I'm not comfortable waiting for days for this issue to be resolved, as it involves another person (whom shall not be discussed except with a mod) performing illegal acts using the SO site.

Comment: @ciphermagi Probably the best option for cases like that is a flag. Give them as much information as you can about the issue, and they'll try to resolve it.

Comment: @ciphermagi Depending on the issue, you'll probably be better off contacting the community team via the Contact Us page for that. Unless it's something basic like plagiarized content, there's not much a moderator could or should do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of any page.